# Implementing CONTAINS clause in Java Collections

Tags: java, collections

Can anyone tell me how to implement `CONTAINS` type feature in java collections. My problem is that I've a list of names.
For e.g:- `List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();`
This list is having, say 100 elements. Lets say I've a name `Paras Anand` in the list. Now if I search for `ara ana` or `ana ara`, I should get the result. Its something like `CONTAINS` clause used in SQL that I want.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Split the search string by whitespace, do an indexof for each part of the split on each element of the list one by one, return all that match

Comment: create your own method called `contains` and pass the string that you want to look for as argument within `contains` method. Loop through all elements present in that list and match the string using `String.contains()` method. If it returns true put the obtained value at that index in a `List` and after loop is finished return that list to the program.

Comment: Removed tags regarding SQL and Oracle since this is in fact a java question

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution: more elegant way and little complected one :) :

The custom `ArrayList` implementation for overriding `contains` and `containsAll`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class CustomStringList extends ArrayList<String> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3513906584235908802L;

    public CustomStringList(Collection<String> aist) {
        super(aist);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object obj) {
        String paramString = (String) obj;

        for (String string : this) {
            if (string.toLowerCase().indexOf(paramString.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> collection) {
        for (Object obj : collection) {
            if (!contains(obj)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The main `Controller` for testing:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class Controller {
    private static List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();;

    static {        
        names.add("shyamali bose");
        names.add("SHYAMALI BOSE");
        names.add("aShoK BoSE");
    }

    private static List<String> contains(String search) {
        CustomStringList searchParts = new CustomStringList(Arrays.asList(search.split("\\s")));
        List<String> matcheResults = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(String name : names) {              
            CustomStringList nameParts = new CustomStringList(Arrays.asList(name.split("\\s")));

            if(nameParts.containsAll(searchParts)) {
                matcheResults.add(name);
            }
        }

        return matcheResults;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {               
        String searchString = "ose ose";
        System.out.println("Matched for: " + searchString + " | " + (contains(searchString).size() > 0));       

        searchString = "ame osa";
        System.out.println("Matched for: " + searchString + " | " + (contains(searchString).size() > 0));

        searchString = "ama OSE";
        System.out.println("Matched for: " + searchString + " | " + (contains(searchString).size() > 0));

        searchString = "ose AMA";
        System.out.println("Matched for: " + searchString + " | " + (contains(searchString).size() > 0));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Matched for: ose ose | true
Matched for: ame osa | false
Matched for: ama OSE | true
Matched for: ose AMA | true
```

Feel free to ask if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Editing this code after long time . I just saw the `CONTAINS` functionality in Oracle today and felt the need to update this code to behave exactly the way it behaves in `SQL`.
You can try like this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Reg
{
    public int contains(String val)
    {
        List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
        String arr[] = val.split("\\s");
        boolean found = false;
        for (String value : list) //Let list be the object of that Collection , say ArrayList
        {
            found = false;
            String[] valArr = value.split("\\s");
            int counter = 0;
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0 ; i < valArr.length ; i++ )
            {
                if (counter == arr.length)
                {
                    if (found)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (valArr[i].contains(arr[counter]))
                {
                    counter++;
                    found = true;
                }
                else
                    found = false;
            }
            if ( i < arr.length )
            {
                found = false;
            }
            if (found)
            {
                records.add(value);
            }
        }
        return  records.size();//Now returning the total number of record matching the input String..
    }
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>()
    {
        {
            add("John fine here");
            add("oh ere");
            add("Fox channel scam");
            add("Michael sam");
            add("Michael");
        }
    };
    public static void main(String st[])
    {
        Reg re = new Reg();
        System.out.println(re.contains("el am"));
    }
}
```